# what does the term "Partridge Family" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

I read an article http://www.details.com/celebrities-entertainment/cover-stars/201205/chris-evans-avengers?currentPage=3

And Scarlett Johansson (an actress) said about Chris Evans (an actor)

> I feel like he grew up with the Partridge Family. He'd be just as
>   happy doing Guys and Dolls as he would Captain America 2

So what does the term "Partridge Family" mean? is it like a family that parents teach children very carefully or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Partridge Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partridge_Family) was an American television show about a family who traveled the country playing music in a band together. They were a closely-knit and wholesome family, so modern references to the Partridge Family generally evoke pleasant imagery.

Johansson's comment about Evans means that she thinks he is very straightforward, wholesome, and traditionally handsome... really everything Steve Rogers/Captain America is!

Comment: Partridge Family is like all members in the family very closed to each other right

Comment: Yes, exactly @Tim

Comment: Who knew the Partridge Family actors would turn out to be so different from their wholesome characters? Arrests for DUI, arrests for assault, arrests for buying drugs, ...